# hover menu jquery slide up and down too fast

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i made this hover menu but is buggy
this my jquery code

```
  $("#right_side li").mouseenter(function(e) {

        $(this).children('ul').stop(true,true).slideDown();

    });
    $(this).stop();
    $("#right_side li").mouseleave(function(e) {
        $(this).children('ul').stop(true,true).slideUp();

    });
```

and this my php code

```
function menu($li)
{
   echo "<ul class='hovermenu'>";
        $result = mysqli_query($li, "SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE 1") or die(mysqli_error($li));

    while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<li class='cat'><div class='cat_div' ><a href='index.php?cat=".$Row['catid']."'>"  . $Row['catname'] . "</a></div><ul class='sub'>";
                                $result2 = mysqli_query($li, "SELECT * FROM `brand` WHERE catid=".$Row['catid']."") or die(mysqli_error($li));
                    while ($Row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                    echo "<li><a href='index.php?brand=".$Row2['id']."&cat=".$Row['catid']."'>"  . $Row2['name'] . "</a></li>";
                                        }
                echo"</ul></li>";
                }

echo "</ul>";
}
```

my problem is 
when my mouseleave 
and i mousein too fast
my menu sliding up and down too fast 
please help meeeee!!!

Comment: Add the `slideUp` and `slideDown` time, like so, `.slideUp(500)`, `.slideDown(500)`.

Comment: my problem is not about timing my problem is when i leave and hover again too fast when my slidedown doesnt done yet my my sub ul gooes too fast up and down

Comment: @Davion By default slideUp and SlideDown execute at 400 miliseconds, so adding it to 500 makes no difference. alirezavalipour Can you recreate the problem in a fiddle? Is your problem that when you pass with the mouse multiple times over the menu, the menu executes multiple times up and down?

Comment: no fixed multiple time with stop()

Comment: @alirezavalipour Can you show us the html? Not the php code

Comment: its simple just think that my mouse on first ul and i leave ul to body and comeback before my animate of slideUp is working so problem start from here my sub ul hide and show too fast is about 60HZ :))

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/97raxhxa/8/

Answer (score 2):

Add the speed to your slideUp call e.g. "slow"

```
slideUp("slow")
```

You can also use a value in milliseconds.

Comment: i know about timing but my problem is something else

Comment: Your code doesn't include it.Adding slow will slow down your slide speed - which is what you asked for, right?

Comment: no ,when i leave and hover again too fast when my slidedown doesnt done yet my my sub ul gooes too fast up and down

Comment: Create a jsfiddle or codepen demonstrating the problem -  it's hard to tell exactly what's happening when we can't see it.

Comment: its simple just think that my mouse on first ul and i leave ul to body and comeback before my animate of slideUp is working so problem start from here my sub ul hide and show too fast is about 60HZ :))

Comment: I understand the problem now, but can't help without seeing a working reduced test case.

Answer (score 1):

you may simply add a time in milliseconds like slideUp(1000) or slideDown(300) or slideDown("fast") or slideUp("slow")
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your script to this one and let me know if the issue is fixed

```
$("#right_side li").on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown();
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).children('ul').stop().slideUp();
    }
});
```

Comment: Well make a fiddle with your issue :)

Comment: Your fiddle has no #right_side and it is not working :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62934/discussion-between-alireza-valipour-and-bojan-petkovski).

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with the jQuery slideUp/slideDown functions when the element being slid up/down has no set height. Ensure the element to be hidden has a specified height.

ALSO, the min-height css property will mess things up. Remove min-height from the element.

Reference:

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/slideup-slow-and-slidedown-slow-happening-instantly

Comment: This fixed my problem after I spent an hour trying to figure it out. Don't know why someone down voted this...